# Using the serial monitor in the Arduino IDE (why is this working?)

Tags: java, c, serial-port, processing, arduino

I have a peculiar problem with writing to serial on an Arduino. I recently changed boards in a project from the [Duemilanove](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardDuemilanove) to the [Mega2560](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardMega2560). Part of my code does very simple serial reading from a processing program, for example:

```
if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    byte c = Serial.read();
}
```

In the setup method I open a 115200 Baud connection with:

```
  Serial.begin(115200);
```

Anyhow, this worked fine with the Duemilanove but now that I switched to the Mega2560 the Arduino doesn't seem to be receiving serial data. However, to my amazement when I open the serial monitor window before launching the processing program that sends the data, all of the data is sent correctly.

My question is, what does the serial monitor change that makes everything work and how can I recreate that in my processing program?

Comment: Have you checked the flow control?

Comment: @William - How do you know from the serial monitor that the arduino actually *reads* the data? Did you have a debug echo message for that?

Comment: Might sound silly, but do you have the same baud rate both on the board and setup in in your Processing app ?

Comment: Sorry about the delay in replying.  I know the data is sent correctly with the serial monitor because the Arduino uses the received data to control a large number of RGB leds via SPI.  Since the display (about 600 bytes of data ever 30ms) shows the correct pattern I'm assuming the data is correct.

Comment: I do have the same baud rate set on both the processing app and Arduino, but that's always a good thing to check. Thanks.  All I can think is that it must be something specific to the Mega platform since the Duemilanove worked fine with the same code.

Comment: Also might sound silly, but have you selected the "Mega2560" as your board on the Arduino IDE?

Answer (score 1):

The Arduino software reset means whenever a serial monitor is connected, the Arduino is auto-reset. Have you noticed this behavior and could this be the cause?

To turn off auto-reset there is a trace that can be cut. It is easy to resolder if you want to turn the feature back on.

This [Arduino Wiki Page](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardMega2560) may be helpful.

[image: S]

Answer (score 0):

The serial monitor only does  RESET to the board. Just try and reset the mega before you run your code.